# how to avoid repeating expectations in multiple test when using mocha/chai

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I have 20 tests with the same check/expections and I want to reduce the repeated function in the end method call. Any suggestions to refactor?

```
describe('my test 1', function() {
            it('response with email id reference expected', function(done) {

                request
                    .post(apiPath)
                    .send(input)
                    .end(function(err, res) {

                        expect(res.statusCode).equals(200);
                        expect(res.body.refId.length == 36);
                        expect(res.body.this1.length = 1);
                        expect(res.body.that2.length = 2);
                        expect(res.body.that3.length = 3);
                        done();
                    });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it like this below. If there is better way then please answer.

```
let positiveAssertions = function(response) {
          expect(response.statusCode).equals(200);
          expect(response.body.refId.length == 36);
          expect(response.body.this1.length = 1);
          expect(response.body.that2.length = 2);
          expect(response.body.that3.length = 3);
};

describe('my test 1', function() {
    it('response with email id reference expected', function(done) {

        request
            .post(messagingApiPath)
            .send(input)
            .expect((response) => positiveAssertions(response))
            .end(done);
    });
});
```